# Relationship between maxPollRecords and autoCommitEnable in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Can Someone Please give me some good example and relationship between the kafka params maxPollRecords and autoCommitEnable in Kafka.

Comment: why do u feel they are related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship as such between them . Let me explain the two configs to you.

In Kafka there are two ways a consumer can commit offsets -

1.Manual Offset Commit - where the responsibility of committing offsets lies with the developer.

2.Enable Auto Commit- This is where the Kafka consumer takes the responsibility of committing offsets for you. How it works is, on every poll() call you make on the consumer , it is checked whether it is time to commit the offset ( this is dictated by auto.commit.interval.ms configuration), if it is time, it commits the offset.

For example - Suppose the auto.commit.interval.ms is set to 7 secs and every call to poll() takes 8 secs. So on a particular call to poll(), it will check, if the time to commit offset has elapsed , which in this example would have , then it will commit the offsets fetched from the previous poll.

Offsets are also committed during the closing of a consumer.

Here are some links you can look at -

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

[Does kafka lose message if consumer holds message longer then auto commit interval time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531376/does-kafka-lose-message-if-consumer-holds-message-longer-then-auto-commit-interv/50537983#50537983)

Now , onto Max.poll.records. By, this configuration, you can tell the kafka consumer, what are the maximum number of records , you would like it return on a single call to poll(). Note you will generally not change the defaults for this , unless your record processing is slow , and you want to ensure that your consumer is not considered dead , because of the slowness of processing too many records.